# how to refresh only a specific div using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to refresh only a specific div that has a class name `image-uploader`.Below is the div structure that I have -

```
<div class="repeater">
     <table>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="image-uploader"></div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

How to achieve that using jQuery ?

Comment: What do you mean by "_refresh only a specific div_"? Did you mean that reloading the content of the div or else?

Comment: you need to use an ajax based function which can fetch the content from server side and then use `.load()` to reload it

Comment: This div has input type which uploads image. Whenever the image uploaded is of wrong format, i want to show the error message and refresh this div.

Comment: what do you mean by refreshing the div ??? You can manipulate the content of div by adding/appending/removing html.

Comment: refreshing the div does help to get the div into its original state/html format

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to implement ajax with jquery. you need some jquery "api" which returns only the content of the div you're trying to refresh.

you can replace the content of a div for example with somethink like this:

```
function refreshdiv(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "refresh.php",
    type: "POST"
  }).done(function (data) {
    $(yourdivselector).html(data);
  }
}
```

now if you trigger the js code it will get the data returned from refresh.php and replaces the content of the "yourdivselector" html tag with the response.

you could even create a function which runs the returned js code to get dynamic site changes done without writing a function for every single possibility for example like this:

-- snip --

```
  .done(function (data) {
    eval(data);
  }
```

you only have to be sure to not return any sensitive data to this.

Comment: this need to be added as comment rather than answer

Comment: net enough reputation to start commenting T_T

Answer (score 0):

provide more details on which event you need to refresh div?

If you are searching for "click" event then this will help you.

```
$(".image-uploader").click(function(e){
    this.innerHTML = "";
});
```

Comment: im checking this onclick of another button not onclick of this div

Answer (score 0):

See the sample I have created:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/G7xke/

<form>
<input type="file" name="files" id="file1" style="color:White" />
<input type="submit" value="Create" />
</form>
<button value="check" id="check" name="check" >check</button>
```

And JavaScript:

```
$("#check").click(function(){
    var fileName = $("#file1").val();
    if(fileName.lastIndexOf("png")===fileName.length-3)
        alert("OK");
    else
        alert("Not PNG");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose you want to change your `<div>` tag on `Button Click` you can use this method.
Include `JQuery.js` file first.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btn').on('click', function () {
                $('#image-uploader').html('Your New Value');
            });
        });
</script>

<div id="image-uploader">
    Old Text
</div>

<input type="button" id="btn"  value="test"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load just a div using jquery .load() function

[use this link for know in detail](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

example#

```
$('#thisdiv').load(document.URL +  ' #thisdiv');
```